# How to copy a HTML tag parameter value into another parameter of the same tag (for every tag in the source text)?

Tags: html, xml, regex, refactoring, editor

I have got a huge HTML form where all the inputs have the `name` parameters set. I would like to also set `id` (to be equal to the name) for every input. Manual copying and pasting would be nasty as there are too many inputs actually. Of course I can write a program that would parse the tags and do just this but this looks a bit overkill too. Any suggestions?

UPDATE: I mean doing it at the HTML source code level rather than in the run time.

UPDATE2: The task actually means replacing every occurrence of the `name="my-field"` pattern (where there can be anything reasonable in place of `my-field` (but will contain the minus usually, so supporting just letters is not enough)) with `name="my-field" id="my-field"`. I believe this can be done with something like `sed` but to my shame I am hardly proficient in regular expressions.

Comment: I would suggest a regex search and replace for this; but it's hard to know exactly what pattern and replacement(s) to suggest without a sense of the (in)consistency of the `input` elements' attributes - e.g. whether they already have `id` attributes, whether their `name` and `id` attributes' order is consistent if they do etc.  Can you provide a (sanitized) example of what you're trying to transform?

Comment: `name="my-field"` to `name="my-field" id="my-field"` @J0e3gan I am not proficient in using regexes unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply use a regex search & replace on the HTML file for this.

Given input...

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Whatever</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input name="foo"/>
      <input name="bar"/>
      <input name="foo-bar"/>
    </form>
</html>
```

..., a regex search on...

```
name="([a-zA-Z\-]+)"
```

... and replacement with...

```
name="$1" id="$1"
```

...would yield:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Whatever</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input name="foo" id="foo"/>
      <input name="bar" id="bar"/>
      <input name="foo-bar" id="foo-bar"/>
    </form>
</html>
```

The above regex search & replace values use [.NET's regex syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but they are easily adaptable to [Java regex syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) or another regex syntax.

Actually, using the [RegexPlanet Java regex tester](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html), I [confirmed](http://fiddle.re/v7h5g) that the above regex search & replace values should work as-is with an editor or other tool that supports Java regex syntax too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use javascript to achieve this: Something like this should work

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
**function loadId() { 
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
inputs[i].id = inputs[i].name;
}
}**
</script>
</head>
<body onload="loadId()">
<input name = "test1" /> 
<input name = "test2" /> 
<input name = "test3" /> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think I would prefer to apply the change at the source code level rather than in the run time.

Answer (score 1):

If your HTML is XHTML (well-formed) (or if you can convert it into XHTML using [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/), for example), you can use a XSLT transformation to copy the contents of the name attributes into new id attributes.

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
         <xsl:copy>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()"/>
         </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="input">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Will convert a file with this content:

```
<form>
    <div class="inputs">
        <p style="color:red">Text</p>
        <input type="text" name="a" />
        <input type="password" name="b" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="c" />
        <input type="radio" name="d" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Into this (adds a new `id` attribute to each `input` with the contents of the `name` attribute):

```
<form>
   <div class="inputs">
      <p style="color:red">Text</p>
      <input id="a" type="text" name="a">
      <input id="b" type="password" name="b">
      <input id="c" type="checkbox" name="c">
      <input id="d" type="radio" name="d">
   </div>
</form>
```

You can run a XSLT processor using command line tools line [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I have chosen the @j0e3gan's solution as the fastest to go, but your one looks the most perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$("form#myForm :input").each(function(){
    var input = $(this); 
    input.attr('id', input.attr('name'));
});
```

Haven't tested, but guess should work.